# Command Line to find and delete Similar files in Linux

Tags: linux, command, delete-file, rm

I want to find and delete all the "similar files as shown below" recursively from the specified directory of my Linux Server by Using COMMAND LINE....

"file.php?p=10&file=load%2Fnew Animations 1%2FAwesome_flowers-(text1).gif&sort=0"

"file.php?p=10&file=load%2Fnew Games 1%2FAwesome_flowers_-(text1).gif&sort=1"

Note: All these files have different file sizes and The matched text in all files is "file.php?p***"

Comment: belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: `rm -f file.php\?p\=*`

Comment: does it work for "recursively" file deletion???? I want to delete all files within a directory which have subdirectories too and i want to delete files from subdirectories too

I am sorry for my Bad English...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you to delete files recursively..

> find /path/to/dir -type f -name 'file.php\?p*' -exec rm -i {} \;